# php class not found but exist

Tags: php, class, structure

I have a project with this structure:

```
/root
    /api/class/user.php
    /api/autoload.php
    /api/api.php
    /index.php
```

inside `index.php` I require (`./api/autload.php`)
inside `autoload.php` I require (`class/user.php`) and (`api.php`)

if I create a user instance inside autoload.php no problem,
but If I create a user instance inside api.php I get class not found.

where is the error?
is wrong this structure? I don't use any htaccess.

EDIT
I made some changes:
I split autoload in 2 file:

```
config.php -> I define some constant
autoload.php -> require config.php + require all my class
api.php -> I require autolaod.php
index.php -> I require api.php
```

now seems to work...the structure is correct for you?

autoload.php

```
define( "LIB_PATH", "lib" );
define( "CLASS_PATH", "class" );
require( LIB_PATH . "/jwt.php" );

require( CLASS_PATH . "/progetto.php" );
require( CLASS_PATH . "/azienda.php" );
require( CLASS_PATH . "/entrata.php" );
require( CLASS_PATH . "/uscita.php" );
require( CLASS_PATH . "/user.php" );
```

Comment: Show your autoloader code, chances are you're using an invalid path for your class files

Comment: I think the path is correct because using the class inside autolaod all work....now I change my question!

Comment: Now it makes more sense...

Comment: `I think the path is correct`... if the path is correct, or the autoloader code is correct, then it should work... it doesn't work, ergo there is a fault somewhere in your autoloader... show code

Comment: add autoload.php code!

Comment: Paths in the autoload.php looks correct, so I assume it's working fine now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, the api.php doesn't have class/user.php required. class/user.php is required only in index.php (through autoload.php) and in api.php (directly).

The solution is to add `require('./class/user.php')` in the api.php file.

**EDIT**

Good approach would be to have all requires of class files in the autoload.php and require the autoload to index.php, api.php, and all other new files where needed.

The edit in the answer now looks like good solution.

Comment: What' the point in manually requiring if your'e using an autoloader

Comment: @Mark Baker In the first question, the autoload.php was something to agregate requires only for non /api/folders files, so I thought that OP wants to repair only the api.php issue.